# Using a canonical link with non-duplicate pages

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, googlebot, canonical-url

I want to use canonical tag for `index.php` and all versions of `index.php` below:

```
  index.php    
  index.php?something  
  index.php?somethingsomething
```

I also have URLs like:

`someproduct.html`

However, I am using packaged software and cannot add a canonical link to just `index.php` and its variations, the software will also add it to `someproduct.html`.

Do you know how Google will respond to `someproduct.html` page if I do this?

Answer (score 2):

As covered [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en), a canonical page is the preferred version of a set of pages with highly similar content.

When you use a canonical link, you're essentially letting Google know that you have highly similar or identical pages, but of them, the canonical page is the preferred one to index:

> Adding this link and attribute lets site owners identify sets of
>   identical content and suggest to Google: "Of all these pages with
>   identical content, this page is the most useful. Please prioritize it
>   in search results."

Ideally, you would only add this to pages containing the same content. If however you add them to a non-relevant page unintentionally, Google should understand that these pages are not related and (hopefully) index them individually.

In these kinds of unknown situations however, which are dependent on variations in content, it's always best to preform [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) if possible. In any case, you only run the risk of a page not being indexed, which you can verify within [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en).